What is the type of an event in Fresh of Deno?
I'm using fresh on Deno.
In islands, what is the type of an event like below?
export function Sample() {
  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => ...} // what is this `e`'s type???
    />
  );
}

I also want to write like here.
export function Sample() {
  const onChangeHandler = (e: ?) => { // e's type??? How can I import the type????
     ...
  }
  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={onChangeHandler} // what is this `e`'s type???
    />
  );
}

The type seems to be JSXInternal.TargetedEvent<HTMLInputElement, Event>, Is this right? How can I import this type from fresh?

Is the type no available globally anyway. Look at this: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/modern-fog-qvls87?file=%2Froutes%2Findex.tsx%3A16%2C31-16%2C80

export function Sample() {
  const onChangeHandler = (e: Event) => { // the answer. doesn't need any import lines.
    const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement; // use cast
    const selectedFile = input.files?.[0];
     ...
  }
  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={onChangeHandler} // what is this `e`'s type???
    />
  );
}

My code is above. This didn't need any import lines.

As freshJS uses pReact you can add event types like this here
    import { h } from "preact";

    export function Sample() {
    const handleChange = (e: h.JSX.TargetedEvent<HTMLInputElement, Event>) => {
        const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement | null;
        if (target) {
          setAnyDataHere(target.value);
        }
      };

      return (
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={handleChange} // what is this `e`'s type???
        />
      );
    }

By using const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement | null, we cast e.target to HTMLInputElement or null.
Null Check: The if (target) statement ensures that target is not null before attempting to access target.value.
This way, TypeScript is satisfied that e.target will not be null when you access its value property.

Please, format inline code in the bottom paragraph to make it more readable.

Use e.currentTarget, not e.target, to have the element type correctly inferred.
